# Set default value from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hook-form

I created radio and I set defaultValue from useState (gender). Problem is that this option set defaultValue before request so it doesn't work correclty. I think that I can use value prop but I don't know how.

```
               <Controller
                  control={control}
                  name="gender"
                  defaultValue="1"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormControl>
                      <FormLabel id="demo-radio-buttons-group-label">
                        Gender
                      </FormLabel>

                      <RadioGroup
                        aria-labelledby="demo-radio-buttons-group-label"
                        value={field.value}
                        onChange={(value) => {
                          field.onChange(value);
                        }}
                        name="radio-buttons-group"
                      >
                        <FormControlLabel
                          value={gender}
                          control={<Radio />}
                          label="Female"
                        />
                        <FormControlLabel
                          value="2"
                          control={<Radio />}
                          label="Male"
                        />
                      </RadioGroup>
                    </FormControl>
                  )}
                />
```

How can I set default value from backend?

Comment: Show a loading animation when the data loads instead of the radio control

Answer (score 0):

components rerender each time there is setting of a state or changinf of the props. In your paticular case, you want lading state before your  render

code would go something like this:

```
const [defaultData,setDeafultData] = useState({})
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

 
useEffect(()=> {
fetch(serverUrl).then((r)=>{
     setDefault(r)
    })
   .catch(e=>console.log(e))
   .finally(()=>{
    setLoading(false)
   })    


     }, [])

if (loading) {
return <p>loading...</p>
}

return ( <Controller
              control={control}
              name="gender"
              defaultValue="1"
              render={....}
            /> )
```

when fetching is done, loading state will change, and it will rerender a component, and instead of returning `<p>Loading...</p>` it will return your `<Controller/>`

**important:** if you have loading state in react it should always start with true value. If you start it with false you will have issues and unesesarry rerenders. Ive seen people doing that.